# RESTful Endpoints - Removing a status attribute from a model

Tags: api, rest, endpoint

I have an action to prioritize an order. So I have an endpoint for:

`PATCH`: `orders/{orderId}/prioritze`

If I wanted to unprioritize it, would it be correct to use the `DELETE` verb like:

`DELETE`: `orders/{orderId}/prioritze`

Otherwise, I figure it might be:

`PATCH`: `orders/{orderId}/unprioritze`

So it's not really "deleting" the priority status, but it is at least toggling the boolean between `1` and `0` for prioritize and unprioritize respectively. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the `PATCH` endpoint with the option `unprioritze` is the good option. I would use `DELETE` when i want to remove the order from the dabatase or tag it as deleted.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the response.